# Create Cron Expression for Bi-Weekly(Every 2 weeks) Thursday

Tags: unix, cron, scheduler, scheduling, job-scheduling

I am looking for a CRON expression which should run every 2 weeks on Thursday. As an e.g. if I execute the JOB on June 24th Thursday , next execution should be on July 8th THU, next is JULY 22nd THU, AUGUST 5th and so on.

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, cron jobs don't like scheduling something every X days where X is greater than 7. You will need to cheat a bit by either scheduling something to happen on the first and third Thursday of a month, such as `0 0 1-7,15-21 * 3` as suggested by [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/404412/396515) over on ServerFault.

Alternatively, you can change the script of the job itself to only execute on odd-numbered weeks as suggested by [other](https://serverfault.com/a/698610/396515) [answers](https://serverfault.com/a/404417/396515) on that same post above. For example:

```sh
0 0 * * 4 [ `expr \`date +\%V\` \% 2` -eq 0 ] && echo "execute script"
```

This cron job will run every Thursday, but the script will only run the command after the `&&` if the current week index is divisible by 2.